# R - for value in dataframe, create a new dataframe with the value

Tags: r

I'm having an issue with referencing a df to filter out values in another df to hold in a new df.

An example:

```
df1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(df1, value))
names(df1) <- c("id", "value")

df2 <- c("a", "b")
names(df2) <- c("id")
```

What I would like to see is for the final dataset would look like this:

```
id   value
a    1
b    2
```

I'm not sure if this is a for loop or the use of the %in% operator but any and all help will be appreciated...

Comment: Why? How are you trying to filter? Your example doesn't actually contain any attempt to perform the operation so it's hard to see what you're trying to do. Can you give an example filter?

Comment: If you're just trying to create a data.frame of those elements in df1 which are in df2, why not: output <- df1[df1$id %in% c("a","b"),]?

Comment: @OliverKeyes this is exactly what I needed - why not copy and paste as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, try:

> output <- df1[df1$id %in% c("a","b"),]

For more generalised cases:

```
match_ids <- c("a","b","another ID","yet another ID")
output <- df[df$id %in% match_ids]
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure df2 is a dataframe.

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=c('a', 'b'))
```

Then merge by id:

```
res <- merge(df1, df2, by='id')

> res
  id value
1  a     1
2  b     2
```